# Stop page refresh at specific time

Tags: javascript

I need to refresh simple page every 60second but i need to stop refreshing with specific time.

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.reload();
}, 60000);
```

note: that the time when page refreshing stop in 00:29 and start in 00:31 and like that ...

Comment: That question looks like "code request" without the attempts you've made...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh EVERY 60 seconds, you should use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, because `setTimeout()` only does it once. And for stopping it:

```
const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (/*Your statement*/) {
        clearInterval(myInterval)
    }
    window.location.reload()
}, 60000)
```